# can I have emacs autosave visited file for only some file types

Tags: emacs

I would like to have emacs autosave my .org files, but all others I would like to control.

Any way to enable/disable autosave based on the filetype ?

Answer (score 1):

```
(setq auto-save-default nil) ;; disable by default
(add-hook org-mode-hook #'auto-save-mode) ;; enable in org-mode
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Control.html#Auto-Save-Control

---

Note that auto-save and backup (Drew's answer) are complementary.  Auto-save saves a copy of the file periodically without user intervention.  If Emacs crashes, you can recover your unsaved edits from the auto-saved copy.  The original file is only changed when you explicitly save.  Backup makes backup copies whenever you do explicitly save, thus providing a crude version control system.  You can use the excellent backup-walker package to look through all the backed up versions.

Comment: any way to have auto-save-visited-file-name set to true in some modes and off in others ?

Then it would be perfect control and be able to say autosave to my org mode files, but for rest just do default "backup" autosave.

Comment: Setting `auto-save-visited-file-name` to non-nil is like automatically doing `save-buffer` periodically.  If `auto-save-mode` is disabled, it doesn't matter because the buffer won't be auto-saved anyway.  You could do `(set (make-local-variable 'auto-save-visited-file-name) t)` to set it locally in `org-mode-hook`.  Personally, I like knowing my file is unchanged on disk unless I explicitly save it, and if Emacs crashes (super rare) I still have the autosaved copy.

Comment: thanks for the tip on make-local-variable.

And yes, I in past also preferred control over my saved files but I see I gotten spoiled by osx autosave feature for all other docs. That why I still want auto-save separately for my code, but for .org files I prefer it to be saved directly rather than having to remember to press 's' in agenda view.

Answer (score 0):

[@jpkotta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42517339/729907) is correct for auto-save files (`#...#`). I misunderstood your question.  I'll leave this answer here, as it is related and may help.  This answer applies to creating a backup file when you save a file buffer you are editing.

---

Customize option **`backup-enable-predicate`**. `C-h v` tells you this:

> **`backup-enable-predicate`** is a variable defined in `files.el`.
>
> Its value is `normal-backup-enable-predicate`
>
> This variable can be risky when used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Predicate that ***looks at a file name and decides whether to make backups***.
>   Called with an absolute file name as argument, it returns `t` to enable backup.

So if the file type is reflected in the file name (e.g., its extension) then this gives you a way to enable backups (aka autosaving) for a given file type.

See also the Elisp manual, node [Backup](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html).

Comment: but are these the auto-save kind of backup so it saves to the actual file, not a separate one ?

Comment: No idea what you mean; sorry. This is how Emacs "autosaves" files: by creating a backup copy of it before you make changes.

Comment: @Drew I wouldn't call the backup feature autosaving.  It only makes backups when you explicitly save with `save-buffer`.  Autosave makes a copy (or overwrites the file with `auto-save-visited-file-name` set to non-nil) without user intervention either after a certain number of edits or after a timeout.

Comment: @jpkotta: You're absolutely right. I misunderstood the question. See my edit. Thx.